# SQL Server window function for date diffs

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Consider I have this table:

```
// Orders

OrderId    Customer  OrderDate      
------------------------------
1          Jack      2018/05/01
2          Jack      2018/05/05
3          Jack      2018/05/15
4          Jack      2018/05/18
5          Jack      2018/05/21
6          Alex      2018/06/11
7          Alex      2018/06/12
8          Alex      2018/06/17
9          Alex      2018/06/18
```

I want to have a query to show the gap days between their orders in a single column like this:

```
Customer    Gaps             GapAverage
---------------------------------------
Jack        4, 10, 3, 3      5
Alex        1, 5, 3          3
```

So for Jack, his *2nd* order was **4 days** after his *1st* order, his *3rd* was **10 days** after his *2nd* order and ...
And his average gaps is 5 days.

How can I write a query to achieve such result in SQL server?

Comment: And why do you think this has anything to do with window functions?  You can google "sql server string aggregation".

Comment: @GordonLinoff because I want them grouped and each group should be sorted and each value should be calculated based on its previous row. How is that possible to do it with just string aggregation?

Comment: . . The function in SQL Server 2017 is `string_agg()`:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How to aggregate `thisRow.OrderDate - previousRow.OrderDate`?

Comment: What version of SQL?

Comment: @Shawn I'm using `Azure SQL Database`

Comment: @mehrandvd If you need to replace STRING_AGG to other alternative function let me know please. In this case I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got such query

```
select q1.Customer, 
       STRING_AGG(q1.diff, ',') as Gaps, 
       AVG(diff) as GapAverage
from ( select Customer as Customer, 
       DATEDIFF(dd, [OrderDate], LEAD([OrderDate]) OVER (PARTITION  BY Customer ORDER  BY Customer)) as diff
       from OrderT) as q1
group by q1.Customer
```

I am using a [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function for the access to the row that follows the current row. Using the OVER argument of this function I am dividing the result into groups by the Customer field. Using the function [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) I get the gap in days.

Comment: please note that STRING_AGG is only available in MSSQL 2017 and later. If you don't use MSSQL 2017 you need to do some tricky things https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/.

Comment: `STRING_AGG` is fine in Azure